# Android :: how can I restart service and run specific function at time x

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

**PROBLEM**

I want to know some concept to do like the topic said

what should be a requirement to do that

I think that `PendingIntent` and `AlarmManager` would be help to restart the service

at time x but I don't know that way to let it call function that I need

Please advice.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

I have 2 functions in my service class and I want to register it

to run one of these two (Depend on user propose) in the future at time x

**SOME CODE THAT I WORK AROUND (EDIT)**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button b1;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmd1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        startIntentAt(5,MyReceiver.class);
        finish();
    }

    private void startIntentAt(int seconds, Class<?> c) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), c);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
        //long interval = 60 * 1000; //
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }


public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);
        scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: AlarmManager shhould work hvnt u tried?

Comment: yeah, but I don't know how to let it lunch my function

Comment: ok can u show any code u tried?

Comment: I have try somethings like edit question to let it call some activity at certain period of time. Now I'm trying with service

Comment: ok did it start after x seconds?

Comment: yes it start for activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58842/discussion-between-adcom-and-jongz-puangput).